# Is it possible to call private functions from a test class QT

Tags: c++, qt, testing

I'm implementing a test class for my project in QT. I have added tests for all the public functions, however there are a couple of private functions that id like to include in my testing.

Obviously this wont work because they are private member functions, but i wondered if this is able to be bypassed on the basis i want to access them from a test case, i dont particularly want to change my code so that my tests work because thats not really helpful, id like the functions to be private but i also want to be able to test them.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on whether this is possible or if i need to change my functions to protected or something and then inherit the class for my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice to only unit test public functions but you can make the test class as the friend of the original class. Something like that:

The decleration of friend should be inside a `#define UNIT_TEST` flag.

```
#include <iostream>

class ToTestClass 
{
 #ifdef UNIT_TEST
    // ToTestClass declares TesterClass as a friend.
    friend class TesterClass;
 #endif

private:
    void privateMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "hey there" << std::endl;
    }
};

class TesterClass
{
public:
    TesterClass()
    {
        ToTestClass  totest;
        // TesterClass now has access to ToTestClass's private members and methods.
        totest.privateMethod();
    }
};

int main()
{
    TesterClass tester;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand the #define bit can you update your code, because as of now i have a lot of errors for putting friend as a class, and should it be `friend class testerClass`

Comment: Alternatively: In unit test header, `#define UNIT_TESTER(x) friend class x; /* or, depending on build */ #define UNIT_TESTER(x)` and in the class just the one line `UNIT_TESTER(TesterClass)`.

Answer (score 1):

Option one. Your functions may be conditionally public private

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST
#define ut public
#else
#define ut private

class Testee
{
    public:
    ....


    ut:
    //private functions to be tested


    ptivate:
};
```

Then, in your test header, simply

```
#define UNIT_TEST
#include <Testee.h>
```

This is a bit dangerous if the tests and the application are in the same project (program) because according to the standard the class definitions must be the same in all translation units in a same program, otherwise, undefined behavior.

Second, and easier and safer option is to declare the Tester class as a friend.

```
class Testee
{
    public:
    ....

    ptivate:
    ....
    friend class Tester;
};
```

Comment: Another issue you may want to mention is that swapping these access modifiers has a good good chance of changing the memory layout of the class. After all, the standard guarantees that members using the same access modifier occur in memory in the same relative order which they are declared.

Comment: So in my class that contains my private functions i want to test, as a private member i add `friend class test;` because i just tried this and it still says cannot access private member variable

Comment: @AngryDuck: It doesn't matter where you add `friend class TesterClass;` - public or private zone. After you add it, all the functions of TesterClass will have access to the private members of Testee.